# Lowest Common Ancestor between multiple nodes in a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph

Is there a way to get the *Lowest common ancestor* between multiple nodes in a *DAG*?

The method signature would look like:

```
GraphNode getLCA(GraphNode... nodes) {
  // code to find LCA
}

GraphNode {
  GraphNode[] parent;
  GraphNode[] children;
  String val;
}
```

In the example of the following:

[image]

```
getLCA(C, E)       // D
getLCA(C, E, B)    // A
getLCA(E, F)       // E
getLCA(A, B, C, D) // A
```

The number of input nodes is unknown. I've seen some answers online, but they are mostly focused on LCA between 2 nodes or recursively finding it with an algorithm for 2 nodes, which requires knowing how many nodes in advance.

But in my case, the challenge is that we don't know how many nodes we get from the input.

Comment: The problem of finding the *Lowest common ancestor* in the DAG not necessarily resolves to a single *node*, there could be **multiple** results (or no common ancestors). Also, node `A` can't be an ancestor to itself, it's logically incorrect. If you need to find a closest common parent, then `A, B, C, D` should result to `null` (`A` is not a parent of `A`), `E, F` should give two nodes `D` and `A` - immediate parents of `E` (again `E` can't be a parent to itself).

Comment: If these examples are part of your assignment, then the problem is slightly different from *LCA*, you need to find the *lowest common node* (nodes), not *ancestors* of the given nodes.

Answer (score 1):

As I've pointed out in the comment, this task is similar to the problem of finding the *Lowest common ancestor*, but according to the provided data sample the result not necessarily should be an *ancestor*, it could be one of the *given nodes* itself.

The solution provided below is based on the assumption that the provided example is correct.

Another important issue is that more than one *Lowest common ancestor* in the *directed acyclic graph* (see [*LCA article in Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor))

Illustration from the Wikipedia:

[image]

Nodes (vertices) *X* and *Y* have two *lowest common ancestors*.

For that reason, I've the return type of the method `getLCA` to be the `List<GraphNode>` instead of `GraphNode`.

#### Algorithm

The overall approach is based on the [*Breadth first search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm. Until no common nodes has been found and there are still some unvisited ancestor nodes, the process of graph traversal continues.

The algorithm can be divided into the following steps:

- Create a list of `Queue` (*a separate **queue** for each given node*) and populate every *queue* with a single node.
- Similarly, create a list of `Set` (*each **set** will correspond to a particular given node*) and populate every *set* with a single node.
- Then check whether result already present the sets (which would be the case if all provided initial nodes are identical). For that, we need to find an [*intersection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of all *sets*.
- Then a then in a loop lists of *queues* and *sets* would be updated and then a new attempt to generate the result will follow. Each *set* will contain one of the given node and all its encountered ancestors. And each will a single generation of ancestors generated at the previous cycle of BFS.

The graph traversal will continue until the *resulting list* is empty and at one of the *queues* is not empty.

#### Implementation

*Graph class:*

```
public class Graph {
    
    private Map<String, GraphNode> nodeByValue = new HashMap<>();
        
    public List<GraphNode> getLCA(GraphNode... nodes) {
        List<GraphNode> commonNodes = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if (nodes.length <= 1) return Arrays.asList(nodes);
        
        List<Set<GraphNode>> seen = generateSets(nodes);
        List<Queue<GraphNode>> queues = generateQueues(nodes);
        
        updateCommonNodes(seen, commonNodes);
        
        while (commonNodes.isEmpty() && hasNonEmptyQueue(queues)) {
            addParentNodes(queues, seen);
            updateCommonNodes(seen, commonNodes);
        }
        return commonNodes;
    }
    
    public void updateCommonNodes(List<Set<GraphNode>> sets,
                                  List<GraphNode> commonNodes) {
        
        commonNodes.addAll(sets.get(0)); // populating the list with elements contained in the first set
        
        for (int i = 1; i < sets.size(); i++) {
            if (commonNodes.isEmpty()) break;   // there are no common nodes, no need to process other sets
            
            commonNodes.retainAll(sets.get(i)); // generating intersection with other sets
        }
    }
    
    public void addParentNodes(List<Queue<GraphNode>> queues,
                               List<Set<GraphNode>> sets) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < queues.size(); i++) {
            Set<GraphNode> seen = sets.get(i);
            Queue<GraphNode> currentGeneration = queues.get(i);
            Queue<GraphNode> immediateAncestors = new ArrayDeque<>();
            
            while (!currentGeneration.isEmpty()) {
                GraphNode current = currentGeneration.remove();
                for (GraphNode parent: current.getParents()) {
                    immediateAncestors.add(parent);
                    seen.add(parent);
                }
            }
            // replacing current generation with ancestors
            queues.set(i, immediateAncestors);
        }
    }
    
    public boolean hasNonEmptyQueue(List<Queue<GraphNode>> queues) {
        boolean hasNonEmpty = false;
        for (Queue<GraphNode> queue: queues) {
            if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                hasNonEmpty = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return hasNonEmpty;
        // or make use of the Stream IPA
//        return queues.stream().anyMatch(queue -> !queue.isEmpty());
    }
    
    private List<Set<GraphNode>> generateSets(GraphNode[] nodes) {
        List<Set<GraphNode>> sets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            Set<GraphNode> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add(nodes[i]);
            sets.add(set);
        }
        return sets;
        // or make use the Stream IPA
//        return Arrays.stream(nodes).<Set<GraphNode>>map(node -> new HashSet<>(List.of(node))).toList();
    }
    
    private List<Queue<GraphNode>> generateQueues(GraphNode[] nodes) {
        List<Queue<GraphNode>> queues = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            Queue<GraphNode> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
            queue.add(nodes[i]);
            queues.add(queue);
        }
        return queues;
        // or make use of the Stream IPA
//        return Arrays.stream(nodes).<Queue<GraphNode>>map(node -> new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(node))).toList();
    }

    // convinience method used in testing
    public List<GraphNode> getLCA(String... nodes) {
        GraphNode[] graphNodes = new GraphNode[nodes.length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            graphNodes[i] = nodeByValue.get(nodes[i]);
        }
        return getLCA(graphNodes);
    }
    
    public void addNode(String nodeValue, String[] parents, String[] children) {
        GraphNode[] parentNodes = new GraphNode[parents.length];
        GraphNode[] childrenNodes = new GraphNode[children.length];
        int pos = 0;
        for (String parent: parents) {
            nodeByValue.computeIfAbsent(parent, GraphNode::new);
            parentNodes[pos++] = nodeByValue.get(parent);
        }
        pos = 0;
        for (String child: children) {
            nodeByValue.computeIfAbsent(child, GraphNode::new);
            childrenNodes[pos++] = nodeByValue.get(child);
        }
        
        nodeByValue.computeIfAbsent(nodeValue, GraphNode::new)
            .setParents(parentNodes)
            .setChildren(childrenNodes);
    }
    
    static class GraphNode {
        private final String value;
        private GraphNode[] parents;
        private GraphNode[] children;
    
        public GraphNode(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    
        public GraphNode(String value, GraphNode[] parents, GraphNode[] children) {
            this.value = value;
            this.parents = parents;
            this.children = children;
        }
    
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    
        public GraphNode[] getParents() {
            return parents;
        }
    
        public GraphNode[] getChildren() {
            return children;
        }
    
        public GraphNode setParents(GraphNode[] parents) {
            this.parents = parents;
            return this;
        }
    
        public GraphNode setChildren(GraphNode[] children) {
            this.children = children;
            return this;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "GraphNode{ " + "val='" + value + " }";
        }
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Graph graph = new Graph();
    // initializing the graph
    graph.addNode("A", new String[]{}, new String[]{"B", "D", "E"});
    graph.addNode("B", new String[]{"A"}, new String[]{"C"});
    graph.addNode("C", new String[]{"B", "D"}, new String[]{"D"});
    graph.addNode("D", new String[]{"A"}, new String[]{"C", "E"});
    graph.addNode("E", new String[]{"A", "D"}, new String[]{"F"});
    graph.addNode("F", new String[]{"E"}, new String[]{});

    System.out.println(graph.getLCA("C", "E"));
    System.out.println(graph.getLCA("C", "E", "B"));
    System.out.println(graph.getLCA("E", "F"));
    System.out.println(graph.getLCA("A", "B", "C", "D"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[GraphNode{ val='D }]   // C, E
[GraphNode{ val='A }]   // C, E, B
[GraphNode{ val='E }]   // E, F
[GraphNode{ val='A }]   // A, B, C, D
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rFD)